# How can I adapt Timedimension to the L.control.layers function?

Tags: javascript

I have a series of layers under L.control.layers and I need to add a WMS layer with timedimension plugin (https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension).
However, I would like this layer to be turned off together with the time dimension.
How can I disable timedimension and wms using a button in L.control.layers?

```
    // example.js
var map = L.map ('map', {
    zoom: 10,
    center: [38.705, 1.15],
    timeDimension: true,
    timeDimensionOptions: {
        timeInterval: "2014-09-30 / 2014-10-30",
        period: "PT1H"
    },
    timeDimensionControl: true,
});

var wmsUrl = "https://thredds.socib.es/thredds/wms/observational/hf_radar/hf_radar_ibiza-scb_codarssproc001_aggregation/dep0001_hf-radar-ibiza_scb-codarssproc001_L1_agg.nc"
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms (wmsUrl, {
    layers: 'sea_water_velocity',
    format: 'image / png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: 'SOCIB HF RADAR | sea_water_velocity '
});

// Create and add a TimeDimension Layer to the map
var tdWmsLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms (wmsLayer);
tdWmsLayer.addTo (map);
```